# php query for inserting data in database table is not working

Tags: php

This is a query for inserting some products in 'products' table of database.
The bold line of variable `$insert_pro` line is not working and saving the data in table while the `'insert into'` is working good.. Please help me to find a mistake

```
$insert_product = "INSERT INTO products (product_cat, product_brand,
  product_title, product_price, product_desc, product_image, product_keyword)
  = VALUES ('$product_cat', '$product_brand', '$product_title',
  '$product_price', '$product_desc','$product_image', '$product_keyword')";

  **$insert_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);**

if($insert_pro) {

    echo "<script>alert('Product has been inserted')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('insert_products.php', '_self')</script> ";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be "=" sign before VALUES in your query

`INSERT INTO products (product_cat, product_brand,
  product_title, product_price, product_desc, product_image, product_keyword)`
  **=** `VALUES ('$product_cat', '$product_brand', '$product_title',
  '$product_price', '$product_desc','$product_image', '$product_keyword')`

Comment: thank you so so so so much...you solved my whole problem..if you were in front of me..i would hug you..i was stuck in this code for last two days and was very frustrated..you are very good...thank you again..!

Comment: Glad could help you. Accept this answer as a correct answer so that other users might find is useful